# Video and Audio files change file type when transfering from Ubuntu to Windows 7 partition

Tags: partitioning, sound, windows-7, virtualbox, file-sharing

[image: Partition open with same file properties open in Ubuntu and Windows]

I am trying to transfer audio and video files across from Ubuntu 13:10 to a Windows 7 partition on VirtualBbox.

Whether I put my files in the shared hard drive or on a USB when Windows accesses it, it does not recognise the file type.

I have tried MP3 MP4 and AVI

Anybody have any ideas on this?

[image: same folder in Windows and Ubuntu]

[image: Windows on the left showing just a file and Ubuntu on the right showing MP3]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try adding the extension to your files in Ubuntu. Disc 1 audio.mp3 and test.mp3 for instance and try it again

Comment: is that just done by renaming the file?
Yup thats exactly how you do it thanks for that.

Comment: Yes, right click the file, select rename and append .mp3